# Generic array contains in C

Tags: c

I have a small function to find if a number is in an array:

```
bool val_in_array(int val, int array[], size_t size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        if (val == array[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

How could I turn this into a "generic" function -- for example, one that can work on an `int` or `float`, or another type?

Comment: You could write it in C++.  Generic programming just isn't part of C, despite the many hacks that people sometimes try.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, that is the plan...eventually! For now I don't know c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey that's quite the question. Let's take an example from the standard library:

```
void *bsearch(const void *needle, const void *array,
                     size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

So that's an impressive header. But we can declare `val_in_array` as follows:

```
void *val_in_array(const void *needle, const void *array,
                     size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

We're going to make our lives easier by returning a pointer to the object if found if we found any.

So as for the implementation:

```
{
    const char *ptr = array;
    for (int i=0; i<nmemb; i++, ptr += size)
        if (!compar(needle, ptr)
            return ptr;
    return NULL;
}
```

This works by advancing `ptr` over the input array and calling the comparison function for every element in the array. It knows how much to advance because you told it how much to advance in `nmemb`. Invocation is something like:

```
    int int_array[16];
    /* fill int_array */
    if (val_in_array(int_array, sizeof(int), 16, intcomp);

int intcomp(void *a, void *b)
{
    int aa = *(const int *)a;
    int bb = *(const int *)b;
    if (aa < bb) return -1;
    if (aa > bb) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You'll appreciate returning the pointer later. If it's not null; convert it back to the right pointer type and subtract the original array from it to get the index of the element.

```
    int *found = val_in_array(...);
    if (found) {
        int index = found - int_array;
        /* ... */
    } else {
        /* not found */
    }
```

`bsearch` is essnetially the same function, but for a sorted array and is much faster because it takes advantage of the array being sorted.